# Retrieving depth value of a sample position using depth map

Tags: graphics, glsl, depth-buffer

I have been trying to implement SSAO following the LearnOpenGL implementation. In their implementation they have utilized the positions g-buffer to obtain the sample positions depth value and I am wondering how I could go about using the depth buffer instead since I have this ready to use, in order to retrieve the depth value instead of using the positions g-buffer. I have shown the LearnOpenGL implementation using the positions texture and the attempt I made at using the depth buffer. I think I might be missing a required step for utilizing the depth buffer but I am unsure.

[LearnOpenGL SSAO][1]

Using Positions g-buffer

```
layout(binding = 7) uniform sampler2D positionsTexture;
layout(binding = 6) uniform sampler2D depthMap;
// ...

    vec4 offset = vec4(samplePos, 1.0);
    offset = camera.proj * offset; //transform sample to clip space
    offset.xyz /= offset.w; // perspective divide
    offset.xyz = offset.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5; // transform to range 0-1

    float sampleDepth = texture(positionsTexture, offset.xy).z;
```

I want to use the depth buffer instead. This approach did not seem to work for me

```
float sampleDepth = texture(depthMap, offset.xy).x;
```

Update: 8/01

I have implemented a linerazation function for the depth result. Still unable to obtain the right result. Am I missing something more?

```
float linearize_depth(float d,float zNear,float zFar)
{
    return zNear * zFar / (zFar + d * (zNear - zFar));
}

float sampleDepth = linearize_depth(texture(depthMap, offset.xy).z, zNear, zFar);
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 It's the same as the first case. Did not want to re-write to keep code small.

Comment: This is likely an accuracy issue. The values in the depth buffer are not linear.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Is the depth buffer by default not [0:1] in Vulkan?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Should I remove `offset.xyz = offset.xyz * 0.5 + 0.5` and just do `offset.xy * 0.5 + 0.5` when sampling the depth map?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Oh right, back to where we started haha. Can't seem to get it to work with `texture(depthMap, offset.xy).x` I feel this is correct but does not yield the right result

Comment: Why would you want to use the value from the depth buffer when you have the coordinates at hand? In the background of the scene, the value from the depth buffer is not as accurate as the coordinate because the depth is not linear and the bits in the depth buffer are limited.

Comment: I was just looking to attempt the effect with the depth buffer

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have updated the post. I implemented a linearization function to linearize the depth result but this only made the scene a little darker, failing to produce the correct AO result. Am I missing something?